# All computers on network get stuck waiting for some sites indefinetely

Tags: browser, hosts-file, adblock

This happens across three computers, running windows 7 and Ubuntu, firefox, opera, and chrome (all latest versions).  I am connected to the internet through a Verizon wireless usb modem.

When I try to open some web pages they will never finish loading (and usually never even show anything).  The status bar at the bottom of the browser will display "Waiting for X"

The servers it gets stuck on include:

- platform.twitter.com
- s7.addthis.com
- connect.facebook.net
- ajax.googleapis.com
- 2mdn.net

Ive been getting away with just blocking them in AdBlock up until now, however the last two have been causing problems.  There are some sites which require googleapis.com to load correctly, and some that wont ever load unless its blocked.  eBay requires access to 2mdn.net to load pictures.  On top of this its getting really annoying having to update AdBlock across all these computers whenever a new site pops up.

I'm hoping there's some easier way to fix this? The different sites causing the freeze indicate to me that it's either a problem on my end (somehow?) or some server side software that got updated with a new bug?

Comment: Wait why are you blocking them in AdBlock if you're trying to access them? I don't understand the question, please clarify.

Comment: @PeterMaxwell, they are not trying to access the listed sites, they are trying to access *other* sites that include content from the listed sites.

Comment: Ok, but if you are blocking certain content, and you try to access it via another site it should not work. So AdBlock seems to be doing its job properly. Can you just unblock them?

Comment: @peterMaxwell The thing is for instance googleapis is required for stackoverflow to work, but makes another site I visit regularly not load at all unless it's blocked.  Either way one site doesn't work

Comment: @PeterMaxwell, the issue isn't that the blocked content is not working on other sites, it's that the other sites as a whole don't work if they include content that is being blocked. For example, imagine if a page includes some picture files, but instead of showing the broken-picture graphic, the page does not load at all. It is getting more common these days that if you use standard blocking techniques to block something that a page happens to use, the page will not finish loading and the throbber just keeps spinning, or worse, the page only partially loads if at all.

Comment: @Synetech Yeah ok, I know what you're talking about, I've seen that before. I believe my point still stands though.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that many sites today include widgets and junk from advertising and social-networking sites. As such, when you visit such sites, they try to load data from Facebook, Twitter, Google Ads, etc. If you are blocking these content sites, then other sites that try to load data from them will block until either some timeout elapses and the site gives up trying to connect, or you give up and close the page.

In the past, you could usually blocks ads and social content by simply blocking the ad/social servers. Other sites would load normally, but leave a broken-page/image IFrame here or there.

Unfortunately, to battle blocking, some sites have changed their page loading structure so that the third-party data is loaded *before* the actual page. This means that if you are blocking, then the page may load partially or not at all.

One thing to try is to block unwanted content using a [HOSTS](https://www.google.com/search?q=hosts%20file). In this way, you add the unwanted sites to the a text-file and when the system tries to load a page/image/etc. from the server, instead of getting the server's real IP address and loading the data, it gets some other IP address (usually your own system's IP address).

If your own system is not running a web-server, then nothing is returned, but the connection was still established, so the page continues to load. If you *do* run a web-server, then you can configure it to return whatever you want (I like have HTML requests return a light-red page with only `[ad]` and images return a 1x1 transparent `.png`).